# Display records in refinery page

Tags: refinerycms

I need to get the record from database and i want to display that record value on home page. My table name is `refierny_about`. I have a model. It was created while I generating the engine.

Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is "About" is your custom extension do this. 
The syntax here is: The `Refinery Namespace::Your Extension Namespace::Extension Model Name`

so you can use the controller is `Refinery::Abouts::About.all`

`app\decorators\controllers\refinery\pages_controller_decorator.rb` here past this code

```
Refinery::PagesController.class_eval do
  def home  
    @posts = Refinery::Abouts::About.all
  end
end
```

and its your html code.

```
<% @posts.each do |a| %>
<p><%= link_to about.title, refinery.abouts_about_path(a) %></p>
<% end %>
```